# $\operatorname{cl}(A)=\operatorname{int}(A)\cup \operatorname{bd}(A)$ (disjoint union)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$$\operatorname{cl}(A)=\operatorname{int}(A)\cup \operatorname{bd}(A)\text{ (disjoint union)}$$

It's not hard problem but I can't think of how to solve it.

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $$X=\operatorname{int}(A)\cup \operatorname{bd}(A)\cup \operatorname{ext}(A)$$ where the three sets at the right-hand side are pairwise disjoint. This means that the two sets $\operatorname{int}(A)\cup \operatorname{bd}(A)$ and $\operatorname{ext}(A)$ are also disjoint and hence complement to each other. It is known that 
$$\operatorname{ext}(A)=(\operatorname{cl}(A))^c$$
Thus,
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{int}(A)\cup \operatorname{bd}(A)&=[\operatorname{ext}(A)]^c\\
&=[(\operatorname{cl}(A))^c]^c\\
&=\operatorname{cl}(A).
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you. plz prove $X=int(A)\cup bd(A) \cup ext(A)$ ?

Comment: @2no Maybe in another question I can answer that. Actually, your question is just a corollary of the result you want me to prove. You can find anyway the proof  in any topology books.